# Vocabulary: name for a variable known but ignored

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

Suppose I have groups (A, B, ...) and in each group I have several inputs and outputs (of the same type). I want to model each output from the inputs, in that case, the group variable is known, but I choose not to include it in the model.

I would intuitively call this group variable a "latent variable", but that could be confusing as a latent variable is usually unknown and taken into account.

Is there a name for a variable underlying the data but not included in a model?

Comment: Ignored? ???????

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What would you think of an "omitted" variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "excluded" makes sense to me.